# Multilanguage in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use a framework Codeigniter.
I have written a library(class) translate with a array words on four language.

```
class Translate
{

public function __construct(){

        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->library("countrylang");
        $this->settings = $this->CI->countrylang->GetSettings();
        $this->words = array(

        'news feed' => array(20 => 'Leunta', 153 => 'Laita', 3 => 'News feed', 109 => 'Leuita'));

}
}
```

In the controller I load this library:

```
$this->data['lang'] = $this->load->library('translate');
```

After I can get access to words from `view` like as:

```
<?=$lang['news feed']?>
```

Problem is that in helpers files there are a words that also must be translate on selected language:

```
function Calendar($type = 'articles'){
      $number =  ($daysRepeat[$i] > 0) ? ' data-original-title = "'.count($daysRepeat[$i]).' записей"' : '';
}
```

So in helpers Codeigniter there are a words that must be replace on selected language and return to view.

How I can do it?

Comment: This line: `$this->data['lang'] = $this->load->library('translate');` doesn't really make sense. The library method of the loader only ever returns false or null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to access models, libraries etc from a helper file, just create a reference to the global CI object like you would anywhere else:

```
function someHelperFunction() 
{
  $CI =& get_instance();
  $CI->load->library('somelibrary');
  $CI->somelibrary->doSomething();

  //  ....
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's a good solution. There's really not a good alternate method.