# Multilanguage in websitewith codeigniter and content dynamic

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to make a website with 4 types of languages with codeigniter.
I see this topic ([Multilanguage in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27296408/multilanguage-in-codeigniter))
but its not solve my problem fully.
I will use the method above to menus, but the content i want to store in db (for the user can change in back office) but i cant know what the best model data to implement.
The other solution is use topic above but i can edit in backoffice language files, this is possible?
Can help me to solve this problem?

Best Regards,
SC

Comment: Can you tell us what issue you get when using codigniter language library ?

Comment: I dont started develop yet. i dont know what the best database schema to have a multilanguage website.

Comment: I have developed 2 type on languages with codeigniter.  I used two column in database i.e description_en and description_fr . And when fetching value from database I add language to description like description_CURRENTLANGUAGE. It will give me proper value. And for static content I used condeigniter language class